# Python communicating with clangd in a non-blocking way

Tags: python, language-server-protocol, clangd

I'm implementing a plugin for one of my hobby projects and basically I want to use an LSP for highlightning code put on a website.

In my case, I want to use clangd to gather information about pre-written C and C++ code. The problem I'm facing is how to exactly communicate with clangd - I have trouble sending and receiving JSONs over piped stdin and stdout.

The biggest problems are:

- the protocol has no strict delimeters like `\0`, only the `Content-Length` header
- pipes are blocking by default which hangs my python code which doesn't know when to stop reading (too much reading = hang untill clangd produces more which deadlocks my program which waits for more output before doing more LSP calls)
- There is no alternative way of communication - only I/O streams. I haven't found anything such inside clangd options and sources.

Here is my code so far - it's enough to start clangd and send the first initialization JSON but then I don't know how to proceed with JSON exchanges without deadlocks or hangs.

```py
import os
import json
import subprocess
import shutil
from typing import Union, List, Dict, Tuple


def make_json_rpc_request(id: Union[str, int], method: str, params: Union[Tuple, List, Dict]):
    if not isinstance(id, (str, int)):
        raise RuntimeError(f"id should be a number or a string: {id}")

    request = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": id,
        "method": method
    }

    if params is not None:
        if isinstance(params, (list, tuple, dict)):
            request["params"] = params
        else:
            raise RuntimeError(f"params is not a structured type: {params}")

    return request


def make_lsp_request(json_rpc_request):
    string = json.dumps(json_rpc_request, indent=None)
    string = f"Content-Length: {len(string)}\r\n\r\n{string}"
    return string

def get_clangd_path():
    result = shutil.which("clangd")
    if result:
        return result

    env_name = os.environ.get("CLANGD")
    if env_name:
        result = shutil.which(env_name)
        if result:
            return result

    raise RuntimeError("clangd not found. Specify env variable CLANGD that points to the executable or to a name searchable in PATH")


class Connection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clangd_path = get_clangd_path()
        self.p = subprocess.Popen([self.clangd_path], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.id = 1

    def send(self, method: str, params):
        request = make_lsp_request(make_json_rpc_request(self.id, method, params))
        self.p.stdin.write(request.encode())
        self.p.stdin.flush()
        self.id += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = Connection()
    conn.send("initialize", {"params": {
        "processId": None,
            "rootUri": None,
            "capabilities": {
        }
    }})
    print(conn.p.stdout.read1())
```

I tried solutions proposed in [A non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/a-non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python) but couldn't get anything to work.

The goal: have something like `make_lsp_call(self, method, params, timeout)` that returns either:

- the received JSON from clangd
- received error messages
- `None` if timeout

Edit: working solution:

```py
    HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length: "

    def receive(self, id: int):
        headers = []

        while True:
            line = self.p.stdout.readline()
            if line != b"\r\n":
                headers.append(line)
            else:
                break

        length = 0
        for hdr in headers:
            hdr = hdr.decode()
            if HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH in hdr:
                length = int(hdr.removeprefix(HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH))
                break

        if length == 0:
            raise RuntimeError(f"invalid or missing '{HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH}' header")

        return self.p.stdout.read(length).decode()
```

Comment: Have you checked out existing LSP client implementation in Python? https://github.com/yeger00/pylspclient or https://github.com/PurpleMyst/sansio-lsp-client

Comment: I searched for but couldn't find any. Apparently I needed the word "client" to find one (found only implementations, not clients). Looking at its code, it's doing the same stuff I linked in my previous question. Seems it is a correct approach, I just did it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the protocol has no strict delimeters like \0, only the Content-Length header

According to [the LSP docs](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#headerPart) the header part is separated from the content with CRLFCRLF, and each header is separated by CRLF, just like in HTTP.

IOW, you don't want to use `.read()` to read everything there is in the pipe, but to read a single message:

1. `readline()` until you get an empty line, put the contents of each header line in e.g. a dict
2. If you didn't get a Content-Length header, the other end is in violation of the spec and that's a fatal error
3. Read exactly `Content-Length` bytes with `.read(n)`.
4. Repeat – the next thing you get should be yet another header.

Opening an async can of worms for this doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: clangd outputs some protocol diagnostics to stderr, how can I read from it (when data is available) without blocking rest of the program?

Comment: Uh, you never even mentioned that requirement in your original post. You can use `select()` to see if there's data available in an fd.

Comment: `select`: "Note that on Windows, it only works for sockets; on other operating systems, it also works for other file types (in particular, on Unix, it works on pipes)." - That's quite limiting.

Comment: @Xeverous By default, yes. But you can subclass `selectors.SelectSelector` to also work on named pipes on Windows. I've done that for a (proprietary, unfortunately) project for exactly this case.

Comment: But you're not really telling us what you'd want to finally _do_ here, anyway. If it works for your use case, you could move all LSP communications to a second thread, and use futures as your async primitive. But again, that's just a shot in the dark here.

Comment: I made it work with the algo you described in the answer. It doesn't read stderr and is blocking but `readline` and checking for `\r\n` + read of appropriate length work correctly. If the algorithm breaks at any point (missing end-of-line or invalid length) the protocol is already violated so the situation is unfixable anyway.